# Creating a pop up without using javascript alert and URL

Tags: popup, popupwindow

I am trying to create a pop up on  alink which have definition of the linked topic. I don't want to use javascript alert becoz of the warning icon. I used window.createpopup but it doesn't works in other browsers than IE. Is there any other function in javascript or jquery for creating pop up with information text only 
 this is what i have in my page

```
               <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-                                                                                            1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/charCount.js"></script>
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javascript/jquery/css/smootheness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>
                   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javascript/jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"/>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PopupExposure').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#Exposurepopup').click(function () {
            $('#PopupExposure').dialog('open');
        });
        $('#PopupStatus').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#Statuspopup').click(function () {
            $('#PopupStatus').dialog('open');
        });
        $('#PopupFunction').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#Functionpopup').click(function () {
            $('#PopupFunction').dialog('open');
        });
        $('#PopupEffect').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#Effectpopup').click(function () {
            $('#PopupEffect').dialog('open');
        });
        $('#PopupResearch').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#Researchpopup').click(function () {
            $('#PopupResearch').dialog('open');
        });
        $('#PopupProgram').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#Programpopup').click(function () {
            $('#PopupProgram').dialog('open');
        });
        $('#PopupPolicy').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#Policypopup').click(function () {
            $('#PopupPolicy').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>

       <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerproxy1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <ContentTemplate>
          <div id="studysub_animal" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_studysubj" CssClass="questions" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="rdb_studysubj"
                            Text="1. Select the study subject."></asp:Label><span class="red">*</span>

                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdb_studysubj" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_studysubj_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="UserProfile">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Humans">Humans</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Non-Human primates">Non-Human primates</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Rodents">Rodents</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Others">Others</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>                            
                    </div>

        <div id="bimarkerinterest" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="questions" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="rdb_biomarkerinterest"
                            Text="1.Select the Biomarker of interest."></asp:Label><span class="red">*</span>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdb_biomarkerinterest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_biomarkerinterest_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Exposure"><a id="Exposurepopup">Exposure</a></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Status"><a id="Statuspopup">Status</a></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Function"><a id="Functionpopup">Function</a></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Effect"><a id="Effectpopup">Effect</a></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>

                    </div>

              <div id="PopupExposure" title="Exposure Definition" style="display:none;"><p>Distinguishing dietary insufficiencies from responses to chronic health conditions\nDetermining the level of intake for a specific nutrient for a group or community and the needs/risks associated with that level</p></div>
              <div id="PopupStatus" title="Status Definition" style="display:none;"><p>Explaining how a person or group of people compare to accepted standards of nutrition.\n Guiding actions related to these standards, such as providing supplementation.</p></div>
              <div id="PopupFunction" title="Function Definition" style="display:none;"><p>Identifying the role of specific nutrients in biological systems.\nIdentifying potential interactions amongst different nutrients in biological systems.\nIdentifying the role for nutrients at different stages of the life span and under different physiological states, e.g., pregnancy.</p></div>
                <div id="PopupEffect" title="Effect Definition" style="display:none;"><p>Assessing the direct impact of nutrient status (i.e., adequacy, deficiency or excess of nutrient.\nEvaluating the impact of an intervention, to include the impact of \n1) a nutritional intervention or \n2) the impact of a non-nutritive intervention, e.g., a drug, on nutrient status or function.</p></div>
                <div id="PopupPolicy" title="Policy Definition" style="display:none;"><p>Refers to the evaluation and use of the extant evidence to support:\n 1) the development of new guidance or policy about diet and health,\n 2) funding agencies making decisions about either the quality of funding applications or the identification of research priorities in food and nutrition,\n 3) donor agencies making decisions about priority areas of need.\nPolicy makers, as data consumers, need a level of confidence in those data to support the generation of evidence-based policy.\n The QBS will better allow them to interpret the literature and help support efforts to determine priority areas of need.</p></div>
                 <div id="PopupProgram" title="Program Definition" style="display:none;"><p>Refers to public health activities, i.e., at community, national, regional or global level, intended to address population based needs through evidence-based interventions.\nThe support for the development, monitoring and evaluation of such activities includes data from surveillance to identify populations at risk.\nThe QBS is intended to support those who are involved in any activity designed to support the development, implementation, monitoring or evaluation of public health interventions</p></div>
                <div id="PopupClinical" title="Clinical Definition" style="display:none;"><p>The context within which nutritional status is assessed to support health promotion, disease prevention or treatment of specific conditions.\n The QBS is intended to improve clinicians’ ability to diagnose, monitor and improve patient status and response to treatment</p></div>
                <div id="PopupResearch" title="Research Definition" style="display:none;"><p>BOND uses an inclusive definition of research that encompasses a continuum of activity from basic/bench research involving studies at a cellular/molecular level utilizing cell cultures or non-human animal models to clinical studies in humans and population-based (surveillance/epidemiology) research.\nThe QBS provides the state of the science with regard to the range of biomarkers available for a given use and is designed to be accessible to users irrespective of their level of nutritional expertise.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's Dialog might be what you're looking for:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

EDIT: Here is a demo showing a working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJxMj/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="triggerDialog">Show Dialog</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">Some text</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    // Create the dialog and make it hidden initially
    $('#dialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    // When the link is clicked, open the dialog
    $('#triggerDialog').click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');    
        return false;
    });

});
```

EDIT: Make sure that you include jQuery, jQuery UI, and one of the jQuery UI stylesheets.  You can find links to all of these files on jQuery's CDN site:

http://codeorigin.jquery.com/

Comment: i am putting the content in a hidden div and trying the link code but it is not working at all

Comment: Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 Aug 2013 18:54:50 UTC
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 697 697 equal to this line  $('#PopopResearch').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
Char: 13
Code: 0

Comment: You aren't including the jQuery UI JavaScript file (and possibly not including the jQuery UI CSS file).  I edited my answer to describe where to find them.  Include them with a `<script ...></script>` and/or `<link .../>` tag.

Comment: Can you please post more of your code?  It's hard to say exactly what the problem is.  The jsFiddle in my answer is working.  Maybe take a look at it.

Comment: looks like the problem is i have ajax enabled pages. doesn't it work with ajax enabled pages...

Comment: jQuery's dialog should work, even with ajax-enabled pages.  As long as the page isn't reloaded upon clicking the link that shows the dialog, the dialog should work just fine.  If you post you code, it would be easier to debug.

Comment: i have added the code if i remove the ajax elements it works but if i include it doesn't works

Comment: I think I see the problem.  Inside each click function, return false.  This will disable the "normal" behavior of the item being clicked, in this case, the link.  I edited my answer to include the `return false;`.